# Reverse postorder in specific category wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I try to reverse the post order in my sidebar for a specific category. 
But i cant get it to work.

```
   <?php query_posts('showposts=8&cat=5$query_string . "&amp;order=ASC"'); if (have_posts()) : ?>
          <li id="senasteNytt">
                  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                 <div class="sidbarContent"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                  <li>
                 <?php endwhile; ?>
            </li>
            <?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: what's the output of this code? In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: The code dont reverse the order...Thats the problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
global $query_string;
query_posts($query_string.'&showposts=8&cat=5&order=ASC');
```